# Little Code Review | From Excel to Json Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, excel

Intro -> I have to convert an excel file, which comes usually in this way:

[image]

to a Json file that must looks like this:

```
"DE": {
   "Title":"Title_DE",
   "Subtitle":"Subtitle_DE",
   "Title_2":"Title_2_DE",
   "Subtitle_2":"Subtitle_2_DE"
}
"GR": {
   "Title":"Title_GR",
   "Subtitle":"Subtitle_GR",
   "Title_2":"Title_2_GR",
   "Subtitle_2":"Subtitle_2_GR"
}
"EN": {
   "Title":"Title_EN",
   "Subtitle":"Subtitle_EN",
   "Title_2":"Title_2_EN",
   "Subtitle_2":"Subtitle_2_EN"
}
```

What I've done -> I have used this node module [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to parse the excel file. The code currently works but something in my mind tells me that was not the best way to do it or at least there was a clearest or a smartest way.

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const fs = require('fs');
let workbook = XLSX.readFile('./src/xls/test.xlsx'); 
let sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames; //--> sheet names
let isocodes = [];
let labels = [];
let copy = [];
let obj = {};
let j = 0;

sheet_name_list.map(sheet => { //--> sheet names loop
    let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet]; 
    for (index in worksheet) {
        let idCol = index.substring(1, 3);
        let idRow = index.substring(0, 1);
        if (idCol === "1") {
            isocodes.push((worksheet[index].v).trim()); //--> isocodes
        }
        if (idRow === "A") {
            labels.push((worksheet[index].v).trim()); //--> labels
        }
        if (idRow != "A" && idCol != "1") {
            copy.push(worksheet[index].v); //--> copy
        }
    }
});

isocodes.shift(); //--> delete undefined
labels.shift();
copy.shift();

isocodes.map(iso => { //--> create object to convert
    obj[iso] = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        obj[iso][labels[i]] = copy[(i * isocodes.length) + j];
    }
    j++;
});
//--> write json files in their folder
fs.writeFile('src/lang/desktop.json', JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\\n|\\r/g, ''), 'utf8', console.log("desktop json file created"));
fs.writeFile('src/lang/mobile.json', JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\\n|\\r/g, ''), 'utf8', console.log("mobile json file created"));
```

Please share your thoughts!!!

Comment: You might want [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead, but check their help section first.

Comment: Oh you're right Andy! Didn't know about codereview section. Thank you! :)